# Windows Authenticated database on WebMethod not working

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ajax

I have tried using SQL Server authenticated Database it worked but with this Windows authenticated DB, I can't figure out what to do.
What could be the problem?

[WebMethod]

```
public static List<string> GetEmployeeName(string empName)
{
    List<string> Models = new List<string>();         
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PHAPPCVTSQL04; Initial Catalog=ECP_IQCDATA_SEM; Integrated Security=True;"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT [Model] FROM [MRB_Model-Approver]";
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchModel", empName);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Models.Add(dr["Model"].ToString());
            }
            con.Close();
            return Models;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
SqlConnection(@Server=PHAPPCVTSQL04;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True);
```

Or

```
SqlConnection(@Server=.;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True);
```

Comment: Thank you Law but still not working with both answer.